# Using Stage Parameters with Nested SSM Parameters

Tags: serverless, aws-ssm

I am trying to migrate to using stage parameters to clean up my serverless.yml file. This switch has worked fine so far except for in the case outlined below.

I have secrets in AWS secrets manager that contain multiple keys, like so:

```
{   
    "UserPoolId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "UserPoolArn": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Previously, I could retrieve all the keys listed above at once with:

```
custom:
  cognito: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/cognito-user-pool}
```

and then reference individual keys contained within that secret like this:

```
functions:
  api:
    handler: src/handlers/resource/handler.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
          authorizer:
            arn: ${self:custom.cognito.UserPoolArn}
            scopes:
              - data-integration-api/read
```

I set up my stage parameters like so:

```
params:
  default:
    cognito: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/cognito-user-pool}
  local:
    cognito:
      UserPoolId: <hard coded user pool id>
      UserPoolArn: <hard coded user pool arn>
```

However when I try to deploy with sls offline --stage dev I now get:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "functions.api.events.0.http.authorizer.arn": The param "cognito.UserPoolArn" cannot be resolved from CLI options or stage params. If you are using Serverless Framework Compose, make sure to run commands via Compose so that all parameters can be resolved
```

I'm sure that if I saved each of the keys contained within the cognito-user-pool secret to their own variables it would fix this problem, but being able to save them all to one variable felt and looked cleaner. Is there any way I can still do this?